# Centering NSIS MUI Header image

Tags: image, header, nsis, modern-ui

As I have read so far, it seems that the header image of a wizard page created by NSIS MUI can be only left or right aligned?

Is there any possibility of centering the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with it—but you will need to modify the dialog, which is stored in a resource in an executable. Take a look in the `Contrib\UIs` directory. You'll need a resource hacker to change it (`modern.exe` is the default, see `Contrib\Modern UI\System.nsh`). Then when you're done you can define `MUI_UI` to the path to your modified executable.

Also consider how you'll get the header text in if you centre the image (or if you want to throw it away).

Comment: @Dulini: don't do it as modern.exe, copy it to somewhere else and then define MUI_UI appropriately (it's better to leave the main NSIS stuff alone and isolate all your changes). Try changing it significantly to make it obvious that it's being changed (e.g. increase the size of the window by a hundred pixels in each dimension).

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer and comment... I changed modern_headerbmp and now it works... I referred to http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=207390 also, I have one more prob that is now the header text are not shown after I ve defined MUI_HEADER_TRANSPARENT_TEXT. Is there anyway to overcome this and display default text on header? I even tried using MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT text but it doesn t work...

Comment: @Dulini: you want to display the text on top of the image? You probably need to go through resource hacking, then. (Make sure you're modifying the right resource.) There you should be able to sort out size, position, z-ordering and things like that, I think.

Comment: Exactly!!! I could do it by changing the control order using ResourceHacker!!! Thanks a lot for your help... I added some edit to your answer too... thanks again